# Drupal location autosuggest doesn't recognize provinces

Tags: drupal, location, autosuggest

I am using Drupal Location module in CCK to retreive 
longitude & latitude based on location (stree/city/state).

There is an automatic autosuggest for State, but unfortunately
recognizes only US states.  I set default country to Canada,
but autosuggest still only recognized US states.

Is there a way to get autosuggest function to recognize Canadian provinces
or to disable this feature.

thanks!

Comment: People will be much more motivated to answer your questions if you go back and accept some answers to your previous questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had disabled country selection. By re-enabling country selection, province selection started working.